# Do women experience more emotion than men?

Tags: gender, emotions

For much of human history, it was "common knowledge" that women were much more emotional than men. This belief still appears to be widely held.

1. Does either gender experience emotions either more frequently or stronger?
2. If there is a difference, does biology play a significant role in causing this difference?

Comment: How do you quantify emotion?

Comment: @ChrisW: Quantification probably isn't without problems but I would bet that someone in psychometrics has thought about quantifying it and produced a metric.

Comment: Do you mean all men and women (all ages and in every society), or specific subsets? In all circumstances/situations, or in specific  circumstances/situations?

Comment: Women tended to be less, I'm not sure what word to use, less intellectual. I think that was used as an argument for their not being the right to vote, for example. The causes for that were mostly social: girls not having the same kind of schooling as boys.

Comment: `Up until recent times it was generally assumed that women were much more emotional than men.` Who says so? Where are the numbers? I don't know such an assumption, so it can't be that general.

Comment: @user: It was general assumed by society until the advent of feminism

Comment: You surely have some citations or something to indicate your claims. Izard lists 10 Emotions: Interest, suffering, aversion, joy, anger, surprise, shame, fear, contempt and guilt feeling. Which of them should be different for men and women? Why?

Comment: @user - for example, [The argument was that the suffragettes should not get the vote because they were too emotional and could not think as logically as men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffragette#Origins).

Comment: @ChrisW: Very well done citation, which in original starts: "A few historians ...". So you identify a few historians with "in general"?

Comment: @user - I think you misunderstand -- I think that: a) it was widely or generally believed that women were more emotional and less logical; and b) a few historians say that suffragettes' "irrational" protests may have hurt their cause by serving to confirm that stereotype.

Comment: What shall that mean, to 'be more logical'? Having emotions is the logic consequence of some experiences. There is no opposition between logic and emotions. `Irrational protest` sounds like a political propaganda to me, not very believable. People tend to call something `irrational` where they couldn't find the ratio behind. So the question is, who lacks the ratio here? To me the historians do.

Comment: @user - It is not the historians who are saying that women are emotional instead of logical and rational: it was the people of the time, who said that.

Comment: @Casebash - Is "experience more emotion than men" meant as a pejorative, in your opinion? Is it the kind of thing you'd say about "the weaker sex": that they "experience" emotion in the sense of being "subject to" or "ruled by" or even "overcome by" emotion?

Comment: ChrisW: Of course not!

Comment: I don't understand why everyone is being so argumentative with the asker. I do not believe they are trying to give this claim any weight but are simply asking about something that has often been said. Who *really* hasn't often heard morons talking about women as being overly emotional and irrational? Is it sexist to acknowledge that sexism exists?

Answer (score 6):

First, there is no simple Yes/No as investigating and judging emotionality is different game in different aspects of emotion. So one cant draw a overall picture of current scientific knowledge and sum it up to a simple *more* as there are too many apples and oranges to compare.

what Wikipedia says on [gender and emotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_and_emotion):

> Studies of psychological gender
>   differences are controversial and
>   subject to error. Many small-scale
>   studies report differences that are
>   not repeated in larger studies.
>   Self-report questionnaires are subject
>   to bias, particularly if the subjects
>   are told that the questionnaire is
>   testing for gender roles. It is also
>   possible that commentators may
>   exaggerate or downplay differences for
>   ideological reasons

From this follows:

- You have to distinguish into social & non-social emotions, look [emotion classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion_classification), **noteworthy there doenst exist a common classification system**
- **"more" is inexact here**, and to be answerable should be specified as something measurable, e.g.:

  - emotional strength/sensitivity (e.g. pain, gender dependent pain-treshold, stronger perception of pain with  same stimulus)
  - divergent emotions in the sense of the above classification systems (does a male orgasm feel like a female one? This is known as a [qualia-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia))

In general, this [sex and emotion Wiki-article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_and_emotion) shows some gender differences. Male hormone Testosterone for example seems to reduce pain sensitivity, and female estrogen [raises it](http://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2003-02/uomh-pat020703.php)

If you want a more exact answer, you have to make a more specific claim, e.g. gender dependence of pain perception or empathy ability are, in my opinion, more precise, answerable questions. Other aspects of emotion are extremely hard to define and objectively measure.

Comment: I made a couple of small edits to help readability, the most important of which was putting the bolded "more" into quotation marks. I was thoroughly confused by it originally. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

"More" is a difficult thing to prove. Different, yes.

> we found left-lateralized
>   activations in the extended amygdala in females
>   and right-sided lateralization in the hippocampus in
>   men, indicating that emotion-memory circuits in
>   the limbic system may be activated differently for
>   men and women

http://www.columbia.edu/cu/psychology/tor/Papers/Phan_Wager_2004_CNS_Emotion_review.pdf

http://www.columbia.edu/cu/psychology/tor/Papers/Wager_NIMG90_inpress.pdf

Comment: Your second paper says very clearly healthy women experience more emotion than healthy men. It's measured in several ways.

Comment: Both links are dead and weren't archived by the Wayback Machine. The first was apparently [*Functional Neuroimaging Studies of Human Emotions*, CNS Spectrums 9(4):258-66](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/8652883_Functional_Neuroimaging_Studies_of_Human_Emotions). It's a survey of "over 55" PET/fMRI studies, which does no data analysis of its own. I have no idea why they say "we" found anything; it just obscures which study(s) these results came from, which is unclear. I couldn't determine what the other paper was, with nothing but a URL to go on.

Answer (score 2):

The only evidence I've found on a difference is that [emotional speech tends to activate the inferior frontal cortex more in women than in men](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15006679). From a study done at The Max Planck Institute of Cognitive Neuroscience:

> We investigated the brain regions that mediate the processing of emotional speech in men and women by presenting positive and negative words that were spoken with happy or angry prosody. Hence, emotional prosody and word valence were either congruous or incongruous. We assumed that an fRMI contrast between congruous and incongruous presentations would reveal the structures that mediate the interaction of emotional prosody and word valence. The left inferior frontal gyrus (IFG) was more strongly activated in incongruous as compared to congruous trials. This difference in IFG activity was significantly larger in women than in men. Moreover, the congruence effect was significant in women whereas it only appeared as a tendency in men. As the left IFG has been repeatedly implicated in semantic processing, these findings are taken as evidence that semantic processing in women is more susceptible to influences from emotional prosody than is semantic processing in men. Moreover, the present data suggest that the left IFG mediates increased semantic processing demands imposed by an incongruence between emotional prosody and word valence.

If semantic processing is indicative of overall "experiencing of emotions" then this would seem to offer evidence that women do experience "more emotion" than men. Or it could simply mean that women can use language to mediate their emotions better than men.